# Twitter relationship visualization in ROR

Tags: twitter

I want to display friend follower relationship in D3 but when there is more friend associated to any particular user a error appears "Rate limit exceeded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limit to ping twitter api (15 times in 15 minutes). So ping as per the limit. 
Or you can use multiple api keys to perform different task.